# Presto: Extract last element from json

Tags: arrays, json, presto

I have an array after I transform a json field and get the information pertaining to its service. The service takes multiple values in the json string and I get all those values in the output. I would want to keep the last occurrence though.

The output I got was:

```
[Free Assessment, Synthetic Oil Change]
```

I want to keep only

```
Synthetic Oil Change
```

As the output, I tried substr by "," but some information is in the form

```
[Free Assessment, Synthetic Oil Change at 15,000 miles]
```

Then I want to keep the entire last thing. I tried json_array_get but it isn't working for me. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the last element from a JSON that contains an array you need to first get the index of the last element with `json_array_length` function and the get the element with `json_array_get`. Please see more details at: https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/json.html

```
presto> SELECT json_array_get(x, json_array_length(x) - 1) 
        FROM (VALUES JSON'["first value", "second value"]') t(x);
    _col0
--------------
 second value
(1 row)
```

The above example was executed with Presto 326.